# Decomposition of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I came across an integral operator defined with
$$
I_{\alpha} f(x)=\int_{ {\mathbb{R}^n}} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy,\qquad 0<\alpha<n
$$
with the following property is valid:

There is $t > 0$ so that
$$
I_{\alpha} f(x) = 2 \int_{B(x,t)} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy =
2 \int_{ {\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(x,t)}} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy.
$$

How can we prove this property is true? I try for one dimension but i can not do anything. Because it seems that very surprising property for me. I even thought that maybe the author meant to say

$$
I_{\alpha} f(x) = \int_{B(x,t)} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy +
 \int_{ {\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B(x,t)}} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy.
$$

Could the mentioned claim be a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, indeed, for every $t > 0$,
$$
I_\alpha f(x) = \int_{B(x,t)} \cdots + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(x,t)} \cdots
$$
Now, the first quantity is an increasing function of $t$, which is $0$ when $t = 0$. Conversely, the second term is a decreasing function of $t$, which is $0$ when $t = +\infty$.
Both terms are continuous functions of $t$.
From the intermediate value principle, you deduce that there exists $t$ (depending on $x$) such that both terms are equal.
And, for this $t_x$,
$$
I_\alpha f(x) = 2 \int_{B(x,t_x)} \cdots = 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B(x,t_x)} \cdots
$$